# how to check the height of my component with hook ref from react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm trying to check if the height of my button is 50 to display a different spinner but even the height being 50 displays SpinnerTwo, does anyone know the problem?

```
const Button = styled.button`
  height: 50px;
`


const ButtonLoading(){

const refButton = useRef<HTMLButtonElement | null>(null);    
    return(
      <Button ref={refButton} onClick={onClick} >
        {refButton.current?.clientHeight === 50 ? <SpinnerOne /> : <SpinnerTwo />}
      </Button> )
}
```

Comment: You won't get a rerender when the ref is set. `clientHeight === 50` seems highly specific. What's actually going on here? Why would it be ***specifically*** 50? It smells to me like you're setting this height elsewhere. Is this the case?

Comment: yes, I have a Button styled component that sets 50px height and another that sets 60px height, this component by default should use 50px in its return. I edited my code to show the example

Comment: My point here is that you are reversing the flow of information here. You are using information that is implicit in the rendered DOM as a kind of secondary, inferred state. There is no way that this is a good idea. There must be some information in the actual application state causes this button to be rendered one way or another. Why can't you use the same information to drive this decision?

Comment: friend, I have several components that inherit from the same component. Each variation of this inheritance has different height, but I render them according to the state of the parent component.

Answer (score 0):

I thought was more easy to get element's height... Anyway you can't use a ref to do that.

You have to use `ReactDOM.findDOMNode` in combination with ref.

But is not sufficient because you have also to store this value into a state variable to active re-rendering after React renders first time the button (to get height).

So the code would be:

```
const [height, setHeight] = useState(); //<-- this to store the height

let refButton = useRef(); //<-- here the ref

useEffect(() => {  //<-- here useEffect to store height into state var
    setHeight(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(refButton.current).getBoundingClientRect().height);
  }, []);
```

Then the rendering:

```
<button
   ref={refButton1}
   style={{ height: 50 }}
   type="button"
   onClick={() => {}}
>
   {height === 50 ? "A" : "B"}
</button>
```

I made an example with 2 buttons: 1 with height = 50 and the other with height = 51. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-useref-forked-4sfc4?file=/src/index.js) the codesandbox

Comment: yes, I'm already using it like this, it was a typo. But it still doesn't work

Comment: thank you very much, i will try here, good explanation!!